# Unable to Switch Database at runtime in App engine

Tags: php, laravel, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I am building a multi-tenant application where I want to keep a separate database for every tenant. For deployment, I am using Google
App Engine and for Database I am using Google Cloud Sql. While Deploying for code to App Engine I am setting DB as CommanDB which is a shared DB
and based on user login I am switching DB to tenantDB. When connected to CommanDB everything works fine but when I switch to tenanttaDB
I get a Connection timeout error.

I have tried switching DB_HOST environment variable at runtime . Variables values is changing but when it tries to connect to DB it gives connection timeout error.

Comment: Stop the App Engine application,Change the environment variable and try restarting the application again